# Anyone know how to create a data structure look like this in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get something look like that in python?

```
Here is the backyard with 0 bones buried:
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  2
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  3
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  4
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  5
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  6
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  8
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  9
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  10
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  11
```

Also, I need 8 bones with a length of 6 randomly located in the yard. The bones are oriented either from left to right or from top to bottom. The bones can be overlapped on each other.

```
Here is the backyard with 1 bone buried:
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  2
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  3
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  4
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  5
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  6
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7
 B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  8
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  9
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  10
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  11
```

or something like that

```
Please, enter a bone number from 1 to 8 and this app shall show a location where this bone could be buried.Enter -1 to quit or 0 to display all bones at once: 5
Here is the backyard with 1 bone buried:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0
.  B  B  B  B  B  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  1
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  2
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  3
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  4
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  5
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  6
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  8
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  9
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  10
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  11
```

and how could I display all the locations at once when the user enter 0? It should be like that:

```
Please, enter a bone number from 1 to 8 and this app shall show a location where this bone could be buried.
Enter -1 to quit or 0 to display all bones at once: 0

Here is the backyard with 8 bones buried:
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 
 .  .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  0
 .  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  1
 .  .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  2
 B  .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  3
 B  .  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  4
 B  .  .  .  .  B  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  5
 B  .  .  .  .  B  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  6
 B  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  7
 B  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  8
 B  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  9
 B  .  .  .  .  B  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  10
 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  11
```

Comment: hmm, that's how it should be like...

Comment: You have two *separate* problems: 1. How to *store* the data; and 2. How to *display* it.The obvious data structure would be a list of lists, or some kind of 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have eight "bones", I would recommend just storing them as a list of (x,y) start-end pairs.

Two bones would be something like this:

```
[((3,5), (8,5)), ((1,9), (6,9))]
```

This represents two bones, one lying from (3,5) to (8,5) horizontally, and one lying from (1,9) to (6,9) vertically.

When/if you need to "draw the yard", just scan through the bones once for each cell and check if the cell is "between" the start and end coordinates.

This is simple, if not particularly efficient.

Likewise, if you just need randomly placed bones that don't dangle off the yard, choose a random coordinate and a random direction. If placing the bone there would make it go off the edge, then just pick a new random point.

Comment: I have added some more descriptions to my question. Can you help me?

Comment: @R.Zhu I believe what I have suggested answers your question. Could you provide some more information on what you think is missing, beyond "does not sound like what I am looking for"?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried and it works well. But also, how can I replace my "bones" with letter B and display them in the yard?